# How can we know the attachmentLayout in Microsoft Directline rest api for client?

Tags: botframework

I am working in a client application which can read messages from an MS Bot using the 'Directline Api for Client' given in the https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline/#!/Conversations/Conversations_GetMessages documentation.
But,how will I determine how to display those attachments, in a list or in a carousel?
As in documentation given for a bot connector (https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/connector/#!/Conversations/Conversations_SendToConversation), a bot can post messages to the directline api and it tells **how** to display them (in the key ***attachmentLayout***). 
In the Client Api, there is no such or related key. So, how can I determine this value from the Api?

Answer (score 0):

In the json that's sent to your client you should see an `attachmentLayout` property:

`{
  "type": "message",
  "attachmentLayout": "list",
  "text": "",...`

What's the Client API you're using? Sounds like it's missing a mapping for that property.

Comment: I am using the directline api. And as per documentation, the attachmentLayout property is not there.